# C# copy data from local SQL Server file to Access .mdb

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

I use below code to copy a SQL Server table to an Access file. I have no problem when I choose local SQL Server Express database (created DB with SSMS in local express area), but I have problem for local file.

```
//Using ACE.OLEDB :
OleDbConnection AccessConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+Setting.UniqeFolderPath+"\\"+Setting.UniqeId+".mdb");

AccessConn.Open();

 //New table, using SELECT INTO
 OleDbCommand AccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(
            @"SELECT * INTO "+desName+" FROM ["+sourceName+ @"] IN '' 
            [ODBC;Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server="+@"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
            Database='LocalDB';Trusted_Connection=yes];", AccessConn);

AccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
AccessConn.Close();
```

The problem happens when I change database:

```
//Error When change to file address or file 
OleDbCommand AccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    @"SELECT * INTO "+desName+" FROM ["+sourceName+ @"] IN '' [ODBC;Driver=
    {ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server="+@"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
    Database='3b26bee4-2cdb-4d39-8400-7abb3debe802';Trusted_Connection=yes];", AccessConn);
```

I change database to each below code:

```
Database='3b26bee4-2cdb-4d39-8400-7abb3debe802'

Database='3b26bee4-2cdb-4d39-8400-7abb3debe802.mdf'

Database='c:\user\temp\uniqueFolder\3b26bee4-2cdb-4d39-8400-7abb3debe802.mdf'
```

Visual Studio show this error :

> Additional information: ODBC--connection to '{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB' failed.

when I change to local express db that created with SSMS, table copy to access file.

```
 OleDbCommand AccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    @"SELECT * INTO "+desName+" FROM ["+sourceName+ @"] IN '' [ODBC;Driver=
    {ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server="+@"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
    Database='LocalDB';Trusted_Connection=yes];", AccessConn);
```

**Problem:** how to copy data from SQL Server local file to Access `.mdb` flie?

Note: I use SQL Server 2016 Express and connect to the database with `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio already has an Export Data wizard that can export data in various formats, including Access. You can even save the package for later

Comment: Why are you using *ODBC* anyway? Why not the native SqlConnection ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, I know but I want to `Export` data programmatically

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can I use `native SqlConnection` ? can you have suggestion ?

Comment: If you have to ask that, you should probably look for an ADO.NET tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are putting your connection string together is odd, you've included the connection string on the command object, which will override the properties in the OleDbConnection.

"[ODBC;Driver= {ODBC Driver 11 for **SQL Server**};**Server**="+@"localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;   Database='LocalDB';Trusted_Connection=yes]"

Get rid of the connection string elements from your command, and specify the connection string on the OleDbConnection object, only.

Have a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/ if you need more info on what the connection string should look like.

Comment: can you have suggest for connection string and copy data from SQL table to access?

Comment: how long to copy 500000 record to Access? I think it's not my solution.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-ado-with-sql-server-native-client for native client. Why are you copying that much (any?) data to Access? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have old reporting service and can't change it. it uses `.mdb` access file. in my code when I set `Sql Express DB`,I have no problem and copy data but when change to file address cant connect to file

Comment: You could try linked tables in Access, connected to a view the source database, then you don't need to put the data directly in the the Access database. Not a great solution, but could be OK.  Otherwise read that link about using native client - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-ado-with-sql-server-native-client